# Regarding GridView Filter in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have a table like this with 5 columns.

```
TableName
-Column1
-Column2
-Column3
-Column4
-Column5
```

I had merged them to display them in grid view as single column.

**Question**
How can i make filter condition query to search them based on user input.?
Eg.User types something as input, it have search from all the 5 columns and return the result based on the search input.(Sorting works fine, please help me with filtering)

If someone could helpme it would be great,
Thanks.

UPDATE:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['ilike', '"x"."y"', $this->variantName])     ->andFilterWhere(['"a"."b"' => $this->ClassId])
->andFilterWhere(['"c"."d"' => $this->FamilyId]) 
->andFilterWhere(['"e"."f"' => $this->PlatformId]) 
->andFilterWhere(['ilike', '"g"."h"', $this->subFamilyName])
```

This is how my old model looks like the fields with familyId,classId,PlatformId are integer and subfamilyname,variantname are text.

Modified:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['or',
                ['ilike', '"x"."y"', $this->Combo],
                ['"a"."b"' => $this->Combo],
                ['"c"."d"' => $this->Combo],
                ['"e"."f"' => $this->Combo],
                ['ilike', '"g"."h"', $this->Combo],
                ])
```

UPDATE 2:
This is how the query looked before merging columns.

```
->andFilterWhere(['ilike', '"storeNames"."variantName"', $this->variantName])
              ->andFilterWhere(['"storeNames"."classId"' => $this->malwareClassId])
              ->andFilterWhere(['"storeNames"."familyId"' => $this->malwareFamilyId])
              ->andFilterWhere(['"storeNames"."platformId"' => $this->malwarePlatformId])
             ->andFilterWhere(['ilike', '"storeNames"."subFamilyName"', $this->subFamilyName]);
```

Comment: you have posted  a similar question some hours ago  .. ttake a look a t your previous question instead of posting the same question more time ..

Comment: posted an answer check if that helps.

Comment: well looking at your code it does not look like what you described your problem is , you are comparing 2 columns at a time with `variantName` and then another combination of 2 columns with `FamilyId` and so on , this isnt what you asked in the start you said you want to use one column in grid view to show all these 5 columns combined and then use the single field in the filter to search from any of these columns? isnt it

Comment: please add proper code and exact model information that contains the field names

Comment: Hi, those were not two columns, it's combination of tablename.columnname so its just one column.
x.y -> tablename.columnname

Comment: Hi, Ok i will create a detailed new question.thanks.
please feel free to check it out.

Comment: updated the post with actual field names, please do check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I will add an example that uses a countries table to display data with `GridView`.

In order to accomplish what you need you have to take the following steps.

1. Create a custom attribute/field inside your `SearchModel`.
2. Add the field to `gridview` column.

   - Define the field as `safe` inside the rules.
3. update the `search()` function inside the `SearchModel` to search and compare based on the new custom field.

Let's say I have a `Countries` table with 2 models

1. `Countries`
2. `CountriesSearch`

The `countries` table has `name` and `code` field and i want to show country `name` and `code` inside a single column like below.

[image]

and i want that the filter field above on the gridview should be able to search if i type `name` or `code` any one of them.

Add field name `$combo` in the `CountrieSearch`

```
public $combo
```

add the field to the rules as safe

```
 public function rules() {
        return [
            [ [ 'id' ] , 'integer' ] ,
            [ [ 'name' , 'code' , 'combo' ] , 'safe' ] ,
        ];
    }
```

Add the new field to the gridview

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

    [
        'attribute'=>'combo',
        'label'=>'Name/Code',
        'value'=>function($model){
            return '<span class="label label-success">'.$model->name.'</span><span class="label label-info">('.$model->code.')</span>';
        },
        'format'=>'raw',
    ],

    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
],
]); ?>
```

Then update the search function and add the following lines just before you are returning the `$dataProvider` inside the `search()` method

```
 $query->andFilterWhere ( [ 'OR' ,
            [ 'like' , 'name' , $this->combo ],
            [ 'like' , 'code' , $this->combo ],
        ] );
```

Hope this helps you out

Comment: Tried the above but the filter returns an DB exception.
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: most probably that is because you are trying to compare an `integer` type field with the `like` keyword, make sure you are not doing that, please add the relevant code you have used for your model. What i suspect you have compared an `int` type field in the `andFilterWhere` change that to either `=` or change the field that is compared. In the above example, the field `code` and `name` both are text. @5.1tat and i have run the above code at my end and it works fine

Comment: ->andFilterWhere(['ilike', '"x"."y"', $this->variantName])   
              ->andFilterWhere(['"a"."b"' => $this->ClassId])   
              ->andFilterWhere(['"c"."d"' => $this->FamilyId])   
              ->andFilterWhere(['"e"."f"' => $this->PlatformId])   
              ->andFilterWhere(['ilike', '"g"."h"', $this->subFamilyName])
This is how my old model looks like the fields with familyId,classId,PlatformId are integer and subfamilyname,variantname are text.

Comment: please add th above code in your original post , it isnt readable here

Comment: Actually the DB i am referring to is in a third Normal Form, the current db only has integers and the related names are in a another database how can i proceed now ?