# How to merge and search for multiple columns in gridview?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

**Question:**

I have merged 5 columns to display in a single column,which the result will look like

```
name.newname.newname2.newname3.5678
```

and when some field is empty consider newname3 it'll be like

```
name.newname.newname2.5678
```

Now i have to implement a search option which can search for cases like:

1.If someone choose to search for "newname" as search criteria then we should get results basing on comparision of joined string of all five columns.(name.newname.newname2.5678).

2.If someone will search "name.new" it should found "name.name2" as well

Sorting Works Just Fine,Help me with the sql query please.

MyCurrent searchmodel looks like this:

```
->andFilterWhere(['ilike', '"storeNames"."variantName"', $this->variantName])
              ->andFilterWhere(['"storeNames"."classId"' => $this->storeClassId])
              ->andFilterWhere(['"storeNames"."familyId"' => $this->storeFamilyId])
              ->andFilterWhere(['"storeNames"."platformId"' => $this->storePlatformId])
             ->andFilterWhere(['ilike', '"storeNames"."subFamilyName"', $this->subFamilyName])
```

Where columns classId,PlatformId,familyId represents integers that maps to a name and displays some names.

Its the getter function in base model,

```
public function getStoreName()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(StoreNames::className(), ['id' => 'storeNameId'])->via('transaction');
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why are you trying to achieve this but you don't think about using orFilterWhere?

Comment: I am completely new to this to be frank!! So, i am struggling.It would be great if you can help me out.

Comment: Try to change andFilterWhere with orFilterWhere ... maybe it helps you. I can't write correct answer because your question is so obscure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regarding GridView Filter in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442035/regarding-gridview-filter-in-yii2)

Comment: Hi Muhammed,it's similar to previous post but i have explained the requirements and more details here.
could you please help me with it ?